# listen_address is not set to the host IP address, only localhost

Tags: cassandra

I am following this guide https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html to add a new DC. I am starting my node with

```shell
docker run -d \
  -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='my cluster name' \
  -e CASSANDRA_AUTO_BOOTSTRAP=true \
  -e CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS= \
  -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GoogleCloudSnitch \
  -e CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=8 \
  -e CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 \
  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=127.0.0.1:7000,<seeds> \
  -e CASSANDRA_ALLOCATE_TOKENS_FOR_LOCAL_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -p 9042:9042 \
  -p 7000:7000 \
  -p 7001:7001 \
  -p 7199:7199 \
  -p 9160:9160 \
  -p 9142:9142 \
  --restart always \
  --name cassandra cassandra:4.1
```

The instruction says the listen_address will pick up the host's IP address correctly, but after starting the node, the listen_address is saying `localhost` instead, and not the host's IP address. This prevents the node from synchronizing with other nodes in the existing data center. What should I do to make the listen_address points to the nodes' IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you referenced are specific to [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) which is the subscription-based (paid) enterprise version built on top of open-source Apache Cassandra.

DSE has enterprise features that are specific to the paid version which are not available in the free open-source version.

Since you are installing open-source Cassandra, you need to explicitly configure the listen address or it will default to `localhost`. It will not be set to the node's IP address automatically.

As a side note, you shouldn't configure the seeds list to `localhost` since it will not be able to form a cluster with other nodes. You should configure the seeds list with IP addresses that other nodes can communicate with on the network. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I updated my command to launch Cassandra based on the OSS Cassandra version. However when the listen_address is set correctly to the private IP in GCP, I wasn't able to start the node as Cassandra says it cannot gossip with peers.

Comment: That's probably because all the other nodes don't have (a) `listen_address` set correctly, (b) don't have seeds set correctly, (c) don't have network connectivity in K8s, or (d) all of the above. Cheers!